# Symfony2 Security System(access_control and security.context) With Database Stored Roles and FOSUserBundle

Tags: security, symfony, roles, fosuserbundle

I am using a solution similar to http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities

So I have a `Role` entity that implements `RoleInterface` and I have a modified `User` entity that is set up to have a ManyToMany relationship with the Roles.

This allows me to use code like this

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$role = new Role('ROLE_TEST');
$user->addRole($role);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($role);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

I can then check if a user has a role with

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

if($user->hasRole('ROLE_TEST')){
   //do stuff...
}
```

---

This solution is ok, but I need to have access to the security context and use code like this:

```
if($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_TEST')){
   //do stuff...
}
```

And in the security.yml cofig file I would like to use the access_control code like this:

```
access_control:
   - { path: ^/test$, role: ROLE_TEST }
```

Do I need a custom user manager for this? The roles that are assigned to a user in the database are not being carried over to the built in Symfony security system.

In other words when I view the security section of the profiler it shows that the user is assigned to `Roles    [ROLE_USER]`, but I am hoping to get it so the system will also recognize the roles that I have set in the database for the logged in user such as `ROLE_TEST`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this was not working is because I was still logged in with the same session. Logging out and then back in again to refresh the session with the new roles does the trick. DOH!